# Can protobuf compiled to static python class?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf, I found after compiled to python file by `protoc`, the python classes are all dynamic, so the auto-completion is gone, it is not very convenient.

I want to know if there is a way to compile protobuf to static python class, I mean with fixed attributes and methods.

Comment: What do you mean by `static` and `dynamic` `python classes`? How does it relate to `auto-completion`? It might help if you can extend your question with examples.

Comment: what he means is that the IDE is of no help if there are no classes created by the protoc compiler. While they are generated for Java and others, Python users have to suffer through useless runtime-level stuff.